# How can I connect to terraform state file in Azure with Terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I'm trying to set up a connection to azure using terraform. I have read you need to use the following code if using a storage account key for the state file , however what goes in the key field and where would you put the below code in. Do I have to save it in a file somewhere?

I got the info below from https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs

```
terraform {
  backend "azurerm" {
    storage_account_name = "tf-sa"
    container_name       = "tfstate"
    **key                  = "???????"**

    access_key = "12345678examplekey"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The state can be kept locally or in a remote location. If stored locally, the name of the file is `terraform.tfstate`. You can consider that as being a `key` by which you can fetch the state from a local filesystem. In the example you posted, Azure Blob Storage [1] is used. Since that is a remote state and you might want to use the same storage for more than one state file, you need to define a unique key which will be used for the state file. If that was not the case, then your state files would get overridden all the time, so usually it is a good practice to name it something meaningful, e.g., `key = mysupercoolproject.tfstate`. For example, in AWS S3 you can even define a key similar to a "path", e.g., `key = /path/to/my/supercool/state/file/something.tfstate`. That might work with Azure Blob Storage as well.

This part of code can be added in any file with a `.tf` extension within the directory you are running Terraform from. The usual convention is to call it `backend.tf`.

For more detailed explanations, check [2] and [3].

---

[1] https://www.terraform.io/language/settings/backends/azurerm

[2] https://www.terraform.io/language/settings/backends

[3] https://www.terraform.io/language/settings/backends/configuration